# D3 Radar chart with Logarithmic scale

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have average score for 4 candidate and i have to plot this avg score of 4 candidate on D3 Radar chart with logarithmic scale of base 10.

How can i use logarithmic scale in radar chart?

Comment: Use the D3 logarithmic scale.

Comment: Can u suggest any Example for logarithmic Radar chart.

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples. All you need to do is change the scale.